# python assignment placeholder for no memory allocation

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, memory, variable-assignment

I want to make an assingment without allocating memory for particular elements. In MATLAB there is the ~ symbol, which acts as a placeholder and allows for the the assignment. For example,

> > (~,b) = deal(1,2) 
> >     can be executed without allocating any memory in the a variable ~.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing such as `x = func()[0]` for the first return value, or `x = func()[1]` for the second. Ranges like `x = func()[5:10]` also work.